# Dialog Popup doesn't rearrange when device rotated in windows store apps

Tags: windows-8, dialog, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I use dialog popups in my Windows Store app using a Popup object with the child set to a Page.  However, the dialog doesn't resize when the device is rotated like other Page's do automatically.  Likewise, if I close the dialog (keeping the Page object), rotate the device, and display the dialog again (new Popup, old Page), the dialog uses the wrong size.

Comment: Please share some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the nature of the Popup unfortunately. You should make sure your `Popup` is a child of some `Panel` (e.g. a page's LayoutGrid `Grid`) and handle the `SizeChanged` event of its parent to update the `Popup`. If you are looking for a nicer solution I'd look into [Callisto's](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/blob/master/readme.md) [Flyout](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/blob/master/src/Callisto/Controls/Flyout/Flyout.cs) control.

Comment: Right. Popup is just another XAML control. Nothing special to make it respond to anything. It's up to the developer. +1 on Callisto.